# Excel 2013 VBA , hour check inside a range IF statement not working properly

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a bit of code for my Campus Food Shelf. I'm currently trying to prevent users from manually entering the time for normal transactions (mostly because there's a training issue and no one's doing it uniformly). However, I need the time option within this user form, in the case of data loss, so that everything can be reentered quickly.

So with the following code, I'm trying to check if the user is entering a time that's within an hour of the current time. If not, the user form should use the user's input. However, if it is within an hour then it should just use the current time, with the correct format. It runs properly when TextBox2 is empty. However, when I put 1:58:33 at 2:04 PM it still posts 1:58:33 in column E. Have I done the math wrong? I just want it to post the current time when the user tries entering a time that's within an hour.

```
If TextBox2.Value <> "" Then
            timeCheck1 = Hour(Time) - 1
            timeCheck2 = Hour(Time)
            timeValue = Hour(TextBox2.Value)
            If timeValue < 7 Then
                timeValue = timeValue + 12
            End If
            If timeCheck1 < timeValue And timeValue <> timeCheck2 Then
                Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Range("E" & currentRows).Value = TextBox2.Value & " " & ComboBox8.Value
            Else
                Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Range("E" & currentRows).Value = Format(Time, "h:mm AM/PM")
            End If
        Else
        Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Range("E" & currentRows).Value = Format(Time, "h:mm AM/PM")
        End If
```

Thank you all for your help in advance!

Comment: What do you mean "not working properly"?  What are you expecting to happen that isn't?  What is happening instead?  Have you tried stepping through your code and seeing what values are stored in your variables, and if they are what you are expecting?

Comment: You might find it much easier to use the DateDiff function.  if abs(DateDiff("h",timevalue(textbox2.value),time())) <=1 then.... should do the trick for you.  That compares the time in TextBox2 to the current time in hours, and sees if the absolute value is <1 (i.e. 1 hour before or after the current time).  I haven't tested it, but something like this should work,

Comment: Sorry, I posted this as my shift was ending. The problem should be fully stated now. @hpf, that seems like it just might work! Let me try it tomorrow morning. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks hpf! That worked. I made it a sub since I use it three times in the code. I should probably work on creating several other subs for these large bulky programs I've built...

```
Private Sub TimeCheck(currentRows As Integer)
If DateDiff("h", TextBox2.Value, Time()) > 1 Then
    Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Range("E" & currentRows).Value = TextBox2.Value & " " & ComboBox8.Value
Else
    Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Range("E" & currentRows).Value = Format(Time, "h:mm AM/PM")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks good.  Instead of the Range function, you could use the Cells property.  .Range("E" & currentRows) becomes .Cells(CurrentRows,5).  It does the same thing, but I find it a bit less clunky.

Comment: Awesome. I'm probably going to do an overhaul soon where I convert a decent chunk of this code into sub programs. I'll probably do that conversion in the process.